# Difficulty updating mime types in installshield web site project

Tags: web, upgrade, installshield, mime

I have a web application that is installed on several client servers.  The new upgrade of the application requires the addition of two mime types in the virtual directories. This doesn't seem to be working in my installscript (Installshield 2011 pro) project.

All other aspects of the app update properly.

With a clean install of the latest version my app, not upgrade, the mime types insert just fine.

How can I get the mime types added in with an installscript upgrade install?

Answer (score 0):

What I wound up doing:

I wrote the IIS section in C# and brought the resulting Class Library dll into the installscript using the DotNetCoCreateObject command.

I certainly was hoping that Installshield would be able to handle the IIS update.  But I wasted a day looking for the method and it wasn't there.